# How many times has dragnet electronic surveillance stopped a terrorist attack

Tags: terrorism, surveillance

How many times has the pervasive electronic surveillance that we live under stopped a terrorist attack? This is considering that the reasoning repeatedly given for enforcing this policy is that stopping the threat of terrorism is more important than every other aspect of society.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the United States?

Comment: The actual answer to a question like this may be unknowable; more than half the point of having a bouncer in a club (as a different example) is to give people reasons not to start something in the first place.  But how do you measure fights (or terrorist attacks) which did not happen at all because it was less likely to be successful?  (Note: I am not saying that all preventative measures are effective or justified, just that the impact is sometimes difficult to measure.)

Comment: @Jedediah I wouldn't say it's unknowable, but it may be classified. Certainly there might be a deterrent effect, but the use of the word "stopped" implies that it's asking about cases where an attack was prevented due to some positive action (disrupting a cell, arresting a terrorist, beefing up security in a specific place). These are definitely things that can be quantified, though it's possible that most of the objective information is secret and unavailable to the public

Comment: Should we count cases where undercover agents basically orchestrated the whole thing?
https://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/nov/16/fbi-entrapment-fake-terror-plots

Comment: What country are you asking about? I'm in the US and don't feel like we have "pervasive" surveillance. I don't think there are many cameras in my suburban neighborhood, execpt maybe for traffic light monitoring.

Comment: As many have pointed out, this question need clarity - which country, and what policy?

Comment: The EFF have a page debunking NSA claims that they stopped 54 attacks (as of 2014) here: https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2014/06/top-5-claims-defenders-nsa-have-stop-making-remain-credible

Comment: @PaulJohnson Then that partially disputes the argument that this is unanswerable, as the NSA has, apparently, publicized their (supposed) successes. An answer could make use of that data

Comment: is this regarding electronic comms intercepts?  CCTV?  Note that I don't particularly mind no country being specified.  Terrorism, at least in its modern Islamic form, is pretty stateless by intent and Western countries have collaborated with each other to notify of threats.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica What makes you say that modern terrorism is particularly Islamic?

Comment: @PaulJohnson In Western countries, for politically motivated attacks?  Death counts.  50 years ago it would have been ETA/IRA and it would **not** have been stateless in its targets.  In France, in fact the biggest killers, by far, until ISIS had been the OAS - i.e. rather the opposite thugs.  Things have however changed, at least for now.  And, as far as the OP's "electronic dragnet" that has been put in place in Western societies, it is clearly targeted at that particular brand of terrorism.  Now, if you aim to be be politically correct and argue otherwise, feel free to do so.

Comment: I think if the scope of this question were limited to the US an interesting analysis and good answer can be done on modern anti-terrorism success, particularly focusing around analyzing a time frame and breaking down John Bolton's testimony in front of congress about the success of the Patriot Act. Those particular incidents are highlighted by them as successes (so this is when they felt it worked), and enough details are provided to dissect the claim (so then you can take the claim and analyze it for accuracy).

Comment: If such a direction were pursued, should the question be edited, or a new question asked ?

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out in the comments, a list of successes would not be published by all concerned agencies.

There is one example from Cologne, Germany. were information from the NSA was apprarently passed to German authorities. The German [wikipedia text](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rizinfund_in_K%C3%B6ln) says so, as did news media and spokespeople at the time; the English one is shorter.

Comment: Please elaborate as to what, (if the dragnet's successes and failures are subject to little or no public review), would prevent an ineffective but corrupt dragnet agency from creating fictional successes to justify their own perpetual funding.

Comment: @agc, the information caused arrests and prison sentences. If one does not assume that the courts are **also** corrupt, there must have been substance to the accusations.

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily follow that courts need be corrupt to issue undeserved prison sentences with no genuine substance.  It's possible that  unbeknownst to the honest courts the compelling evidence used to convict is negligently incomplete or even bogus, (*i.e.* falsified by the corrupt dragnet agency), or that a merciful court must follow harsh statutory sentencing (or pre-trial holding) guidelines irrespective of what most judges consider just or reasonable.